# Dell and Jupiter are they compatible?

Tags: dell, jupiter

I have installed Jupiter on my Dell Inspiron 1520 with Ubuntu 10.04 but I am not able to choose the mode, I don't have the line "performance mode".

How can that be?

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jupiter works fine with my Dell Latitude E6530 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Apparently Lucid (10.04) has only an older release of jupiter (0.0.53-2). The next versions of Ubuntu have an updated version 0.1.2-1. The first thing to do is to update your Jupiter version.

You may want to [contact the webupd8 team](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team) and kindly ask them if they could provide an updated version for Lucid.

If they won't do that, you could try to install it from source but it seems a bit more difficult.